# fail2ban:11 lines must begin with a keyword or a filename (possibly in double quotes)

Tags: logrotate, fail2ban

I am rotating the logs of my Fail2Ban service on a daily basis, but, I keep getting this error on a daily basis:

```
/etc/cron.daily/logrotate:
error: fail2ban:11 lines must begin with a keyword or a filename (possibly in double quotes)
```

Here's my `/etc/cron.daily/logrotate file`

```
#!/bin/sh

# Clean non existent log file entries from status file
cd /var/lib/logrotate
test -e status || touch status
head -1 status > status.clean
sed 's/"//g' status | while read logfile date
do
    [ -e "$logfile" ] && echo "\"$logfile\" $date"
done >> status.clean
mv status.clean status

test -x /usr/sbin/logrotate || exit 0
/usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf
```

Here's my 11th line:

```
mv status.clean status
```

As per the error, this line has error. I don't seem to understand what exactly is wrong with this line of file??

Here's my `/etc/logrotate.d/fail2ban` file:

```
/var/log/fail2ban.log {
    monthly
    rotate 13
    compress
    delaycompress
    missingok
    notifempty
    postrotate
    fail2ban-client flushlogs 1>/dev/null
    endscript
    640 fail2ban adm
    create 640 root adm
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error message isn't coming from the shell script, instead it's coming from logrotate. So that's line 11 of the logrotate config file `fail2ban`, not line 11 of the cron.daily script.

It looks like you've made a mistake editing your logrotate config file; line 11 is `640 fail2ban adm` — which is indeed not a valid thing to have there. Maybe you meant that to be part of the `create` line below?

I checked the config file on a Debian Jessie box I have fail2ban running on, and it looks like this:

```
/var/log/fail2ban.log {

    weekly
    rotate 4
    compress

    delaycompress
    missingok
    postrotate
        fail2ban-client flushlogs 1>/dev/null
    endscript

    # If fail2ban runs as non-root it still needs to have write access
    # to logfiles.
    # create 640 fail2ban adm
    create 640 root adm
}
```

... so indeed that should have create in front of it (and one of the two should be commented out/deleted).

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that the 11th line of the configuration is at fault. Not the 11th line of the logrotate script.

```
640 fail2ban adm
```